# Duo Security Admin API users request failed using in Java

Tags: java, duosecurity

I am using Duo Security Admin API. But when I call the api using below code it shows:

```
Get Users request failed with HTTP (response code: 401)
```

Here is my java code:

```
    void users(){

    // Duo Admin API credentials and API hostname
    String integrationKey = "DI7ABPU9TUJQO14RET9Q";
    String secretKey = "YzDs7ZeQGMllravxDQxcn4jNAwyqF42P1XBDdGd2";
    String apiHostname = "api-d221a358.duosecurity.com";

    try {

        String usersUrl = "https://" + apiHostname + "/admin/v1/users";
        // Create URL object
        URL url = new URL(usersUrl);

        // Open a connection to the URL
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set request method to GET
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // Set request headers
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + getBase64Credentials(integrationKey, secretKey));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Date", OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Get the HTTP response code
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // Read and print the response (list of users)
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }

                System.out.println("List of Users: " + response.toString());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Get Users request failed with HTTP response code: " + responseCode);
        }

        // Close the connection
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Encode credentials as Base64
private static String getBase64Credentials(String integrationKey, String secretKey) {
    String credentials = integrationKey + ":" + secretKey;
    return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());
}
```

What is the mistake i have done with my code?
Is it right way to call Duo Security Admin API?

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

For get user Duo admin API code that works for me is

The generate signature code is

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class GenerateSignature {

    public String generateTheToken(List<String> urlArgs, Map<String, String> params, String ikey, String skey)  {
        String canonicalString = generatecanonicalString(urlArgs,params);
        return getAPISignature(canonicalString,ikey,skey);
    }

    public String generatecanonicalString(List<String> urlArgs, Map<String, String> params)
    {
        String canonicalString = String.join("\n", urlArgs);
        canonicalString+="\n";
        String parametersString=params.entrySet().stream().map(entry->entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
        canonicalString+=parametersString;
        System.out.println(canonicalString);
        return canonicalString;
    }

    public String getAPISignature(String url,String ikey,String skey)  {

        Mac sha1Hmac = null;
        try {
            sha1Hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA1");
            sha1Hmac.init(secretKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("error in");
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
        byte[] signatureBytes = sha1Hmac.doFinal(url.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String  signature= Hex.encodeHexString(signatureBytes);
        String auth = ikey + ":" + signature;
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

get users service class is

```
package com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.service;

import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.utilies.GenerateSignature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Service
public class getUsers {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

    private String currentTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());

    @Autowired
    private GenerateSignature generateSignature;


    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public Object getUser() throws Exception {
        String ikey = "DIEZT523RM4GZ4ETBJBQ";
        String skey = "3z9e75OxFp7TuxzHJDWtctntsp2hu0UlkRgr9VxQ";
        String host="api-43c07036.duosecurity.com";
        String userspath="/admin/v1/users";

        String url = "https://api-43c07036.duosecurity.com/admin/v1/users";
        List<String> urlArgs = List.of(currentTime, "GET", host, userspath);
        String token = generateSignature.generateTheToken(urlArgs, Map.of(), ikey,skey);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.DATE, currentTime);
        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Object> ciscoDuoResponse = restTemplate.
                exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
        System.out.println(ciscoDuoResponse.getBody());
        return ciscoDuoResponse.getBody();
    }


}
```

The main class is

```
package com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator;

import com.ciscoduo.bulkgenerator.service.getUsers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BulkgeneratorApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private getUsers getUsers;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BulkgeneratorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

     getUsers.getUser();

    }
}
```